# iPhone: turning off default text tone also turns off contact text tones

Tags: iphone, audio, text

I used to be able to turn the default text message tone to none and set the text tone for specific contacts so that I'd only hear texts from my contacts. This no longer seems to work. Turning off the text tone seems to turn off all my contacts. Is this correct and if so, at which iOS version did this change?

Comment: Which model of iPhone and what version of iOS, please? Have you recently updated iOS, and if so, from which version originally?

Comment: @IconDaemon I actually switched from an iPhone 6 to an iPhone 11. I kept all my settings in the move. I'm at whatever is the latest iOS version. It seems to have been like this since the move. What is the expected behavior in current iOS?